# How to modify (encode and decode) routes id, but without changes in the model or controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to expose my database ids and encode/decode the id with routes helper. For encoding I use [Hashids](https://github.com/peterhellberg/hashids.rb) gem.

Now I have:

routes.rb

```
get 'companies/:id/:year', to: 'company#show', as: 'companies'
```

company url:

```
/companies/1/2015
```

For id encoding I have encode/decode helper methods:

```
def encode(id)
   # encode...
   return 'ABC123'
end

def decode(hashid)
   # decode...
   return 1
end
```

How I can implemented, that id will be with routes helper converted?
So must show the URL:

```
/companies/ABC123/2015
```

and controller must get automatically params with id 1.

Comment: did you try friendly id https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Comment: I use this in other projects, but I do not like it. I will make that without changes in the model or controller. It must be generic implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your answers! But I wont to decode params id without changes in the model or controller. After long consideration, I have decided the params id to manipulate, before controller get params. I manipulate params in routes Constraints.

#### example helper:

encoding_helper.rb

```
module EncodingHelper
  def encode(id)
    # encode...
    return 'ABC123'
  end

  def decode(hashid)
    # decode...
    return 1
  end
end
```

#### Create path with a encode id:

```
companies_path(id: encode(1), year: 2015) # => /companies/ABC123/2015
```

#### Manipulate params in routes Constraints:

lib/Constraints/decode_company_id.rb

```
module Constraints
  class DecodeId
    extend EncodingHelper

    def self.matches?(request)
      request.params['id'] = decode(request.params['id']).to_s if request.params['id'].present?
      true
    end
  end
end
```

config/routes.rb

```
constraints(Constraints::DecodeId) do
  get 'companies/:id/:year', to: 'company#show', as: 'companies'
end
```

After decode params id with constraints und without manipulation in controller, params id is 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the to_param method for this.

```
#in Company
def to_param
  self.encoded_id
end

def encoded_id
  self.class.encode_id(self.id)
end

def find_by_encoded_id(encoded_id)
  self.find_by_id(self.class.decode_id(encoded_id)
end

#class methods
class << self
  def encode_id(id)
    #encoding algorithm here
  end

  def decode_id(encoded_id)
    #decoding algorithm here
  end
end
```

this will mean that urls featuring the id of the company will actually use the encoded_id instead, assuming you pass through the company object to a path helper, eg `company_path(@company)`.

Then, in your companies controller, you just need to make sure that you `find_by_encoded_id(params[:id])` rather than `find_by_id(params[:id])`.

Answer (score 0):

Rails router shouldn't be doing any decoding:

> [The Rails router recognizes URLs and dispatches them to a controller's action.](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

The logic *should* belong to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

When your controller receives an encoded response:

```
#Appropriate controller

def show
  Company.decode(params[:id])
end
```

This work work nicely if you slightly adjust your model method to:

```
def self.decode(code)
  # decode => get id
  find(id) #returns Company object
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this. custom method of friendly id

in model

```
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :decode

  # Try building a slug based on the following fields in
  # increasing order of specificity.
  def decode
     conditional_check(self.id)
  end

  private

  def conditional_check(id)
     return "ABC123" if id == 1
  end
```